# Can I Translate a Pasted Time Value in an Excel Cell So That It Is Stored and Displayed Correctly?

Tags: excel, time, format, formula, cell

Whenever I input a time in the Excel cell it is not recognized. Given the custom format for the cell(s) that I am using, a recognized value inputted into the formula bar will be displayed correctly as "5:00p". The custom cell format I am using is shown below:

[image: Custom cell format]

If I put "5:00p" in the cell/formula bar it does not store the value correctly so that formulas in other cells can run correctly. In order for it to recognize the value it has to look like what is shown below:

[image: Formula bar value]

How do I adjust the settings or translate the pasted text so that if I copy and paste "5:00p" into the cell it will display as "5:00p" and store the correct time value so other calculations can still run?

[image: Displayed time]

Comment: The cell formatting does **not** have any affect on either how the value is displayed in the *formula bar* or on how Excel will parse the time you input. Excel will parse your time input according to your Windows Regional Settings. The formatting only alters what you see in the worksheet cell. To *translate pasted text*, you will need ot use VBA. Or you could use text that is in a format Excel will recognize (eg `5 p` instead of `5p`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a time with AM/PM then use this form:

```
5:0 PM
```

The space between the value and the abbreviations (AM/PM) is essential.

If your input not corresponds to these standards then with a VBA code first convert it to a date/time, then apply the custom display format for the converted value.